# Arreglo variable en C

Tags: c, array

He realizado un código en el cual le indico la cantidad de valores que tendrá mi arreglo, los introduce bien pero luego no me visualiza nada. No se donde esta el fallo creo que estoy devolviendo algo mal.

Código:

```
//Prototipos de funciones
int introducirDatos(int cantidad,int array[]);
void visualizarDatos(int cantidad,int array[]);

int main()
{
    int cantidad,array[cantidad];

    introducirDatos(cantidad,array);
    visualizarDatos(cantidad,array);

    return 0;
}

int introducirDatos(int cantidad,int array[])
{   
     printf("Introduce la cantidad de valores para el array: ");
     scanf("%d",&cantidad);

    for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++)
    {
        printf("Introduzca valor: ");
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }
    return array[cantidad];
}

void visualizarDatos(int cantidad,int array[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++)
    {
        printf("  %d",array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void introducirDatos(int cantidad,int array[]);
void visualizarDatos(int cantidad,int array[]);

int main()
{
    /* Cantidad */
    int cantidad;

    /* Introducimos la cantidad */
    printf("Introduce la cantidad de valores para el array: ");
    scanf("%d",&cantidad);

    /* Arreglo */
    int array[cantidad];

    introducirDatos(cantidad,array);
    visualizarDatos(cantidad,array);

    return 0;
}

void introducirDatos(int cantidad,int array[])
{
    for(int i=0;i < cantidad;i++)
    {
        printf("Introduzca valor: ");
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }

    return;
}

void visualizarDatos(int cantidad,int array[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++)
    {
        printf("  %d",array[i]);
    }
}
```

---

### Explicación

Voy a explicar el cambio por partes:

---

#### Primero

La función main(), ha quedado así:

```
int main()
{
    /* Cantidad */
    int cantidad;

    /* Introducimos la cantidad */
    printf("Introduce la cantidad de valores para el array: ");
    scanf("%d",&cantidad);

    /* Arreglo */
    int array[cantidad];

    introducirDatos(cantidad,array);
    visualizarDatos(cantidad,array);

    return 0;
}
```

Es decir, en la función main se hara la inicialización del arreglo, y de allí se pasara como parámetro a las otras funciones.

---

#### Segundo

Como podemos pasar un arreglo sin necesidad de hacer uso a los pasos por referencia, hemos dejado la función introducirDatos, así:

```
void introducirDatos(int cantidad,int array[])
{
    for(int i=0;i < cantidad;i++)
    {
        printf("Introduzca valor: ");
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }

    return;
}
```

Es decir, la inserción de los datos en el arreglo sera lo único que se realiza en el procedimento. Ya que es un procedimiento, no es necesario retornar nada, ya que como hemos pasado el arreglo como un parámetro, este tiene acceso a modificarlo, ya que se hace un paso del parametro como referencia, podria decirse.

---

#### Tercero

En una explicación más clara del algoritmo que sigue el código, podríamos decir que es la siguiente:

> Pedimos la `cantidad` de valores, posteriormente, inicializamos el arreglo con dicha `cantidad`, asi pasamos el arreglo como parametro a las funciones `introducirDatos`, para que allo se llene el arreglo y posteriormente a la funcion `visualizarDatos` para imprimir el contenido del arreglo.

Comment: Perfecto amigo, muy claro y me he dado cuenta de mis fallos, muchas gracias!!